# Careers 2.0 doesn't remember city?

Tags: bug, jobs

I modified the city field, did a save.  Tried to print to pdf / view my profile, still has my old city name.  Logged out completely, cleared history / cache / cookies / etc.  Logged back in, still the city is my prior city.  How does one update the city field?  If it matters I'm using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93 m